# Получить артикул из квадратных скобок в 1c 8.3

Tags: 1с

Есть строка вида:

```
строкаполноенаименование = "[34-79]Ступичный подшипник"
```

Как мне программно в 1с получить из `строкаполноенаименование`, чтобы было `строкаартикул =3479`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
строкаартикул =СтрПолучитьСтроку(СтрЗаменить(СтрПолучитьСтроку(СтрЗаменить(строкаполноенаименование,"[",Символы.ПС),2)"]",Символы.ПС),1);
```

:)

Само собой, тут не проверяется, что квадратные скобки в строке ЕСТЬ. А по-хорошему, проверять надо, бо ежели их нет, будет неловко...

Comment: Боже, это так выглядит код на `1c`?

Answer (score 0):

```
СтрНаименование = строкаполноенаименование;
п2 = Найти(СтрНаименование , "]");
Если п2<>0 Тогда
  СтрНаименование = Лев(СтрНаименование , п2-1);
  п1 = Найти(СтрНаименование , "[");
  Если п1<>0 Тогда
     СтрНаименование = Сред(СтрНаименование, п1+1);
     СтрНаименование = СтрЗаменить(СтрНаименование,"-","");
     СтрНаименование = СокрЛП(СтрНаименование);
     // СтрНаименование = "3479"
  КонецЕсли;
КонецЕсли;
```